# cocos-2dx with native features and views

Tags: android, ios, mobile, game-engine, cocos2d-x

I am starting to write a project using cocos-2dx. I chose cocos2dx because its cross platform. But I also want to use some native buttons and many other native features. Basically the whole app will be in native code and only the game playing part would be in cocos-2dx. I just want to know if this is a good appproach or if it has any big flaw in it? the other option will be to write the whole game in cocos2dx and write wrappers to call native functions to do native stuff.

Thanks in advance for all the answers :)

Comment: It defies the whole purpose of a cross-platform engine, don't you think? You may be better off going native all the way, and later port by refactoring all of your code, or by using Apportable. Of course you would only do so if the App is successful enough on one platform to begin with. Time saved, headaches avoided.

Comment: I think writing wrapper classes is a better solution. There are always requirements, where you have to use native code. But if you have written the wrappers then it is easy to port to other platforms. I always write wrappers wherever I need to use native code. For example, playing videos.